# CMAKE: Could NOT find Boost (missing: date_time) (found suitable version "1.76.0", minimum required is "1.76.0")

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm trying to add boost components date_time in a c++ program using CMake on Windows 10. I'm writing down what I have done so far. Following is the code in CMakeLists.txt

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for cmake boost with lib, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)

project ("hello")
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF) 
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)  
set(Boost_DEBUG ON)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF) 
find_package(Boost 1.76.0 COMPONENTS date_time) 

if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR}) 
    add_executable(progname file1.cxx file2.cxx) 
    target_link_libraries(progname ${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR})
endif()

add_executable(hello hello.cpp)
```

Remember that I have set environment variables `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` , `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` and `BOOST_ROOT` as `C:\boost_1_76_0` , `C:\boost_1_76_0\stage\lib` and `C:\boost_1_76_0 respectively`.

I keep getting this error.

```
-- Could NOT find Boost (missing: date_time) (found suitable version "1.76.0", minimum required is "1.76.0")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/jan.muhammad/source/repos/boost in cmake
```

Following are the warnings:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     CMake Warning (dev) at C:\Users\jan.muhammad\source\repos\boost in cmake\CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package):
  Policy CMP0074 is not set: find_package uses <PackageName>_ROOT variables.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0074" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Environment variable Boost_ROOT is set to:

    C:\boost_1_76_0

  For compatibility, CMake is ignoring the variable.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.   hello   C:\Users\jan.muhammad\source\repos\boost in cmake\CMakeLists.txt    12  
Warning     CMake Warning at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1354 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets       C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake   1354
```

Here's the console output after `cmake .` using Boost_DEBUG:

```
PS C:\Users\jan.muhammad\source\repos\boost in cmake> cmake .
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:4 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30040.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30040.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30037/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30037/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package):
  Policy CMP0074 is not set: find_package uses <PackageName>_ROOT variables.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0074" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Environment variable Boost_ROOT is set to:

    C:\boost_1_76_0

  For compatibility, CMake is ignoring the variable.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1657 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1658 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ="ON"
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1659 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = "OFF"
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1660 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = "OFF"
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1661 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1662 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1694 ] BOOST_ROOT = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1695 ] ENV{BOOST_ROOT} = "C:\boost_1_76_0"
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1696 ] BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1697 ] ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} = "C:\boost_1_76_0"
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1698 ] BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1699 ] ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} = "C:\boost_1_76_0\stage\lib"
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1771 ] _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = "C:/boost_1_76_0;C:/boost_1_76_0/include;C:/boost_1_76_0;PATHS;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/sw/local/include"
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1772 ] _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1787 ] location of version.hpp: C:/boost_1_76_0/boost/version.hpp
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1827 ] Boost_VERSION = "107600"
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1828 ] Boost_VERSION_STRING = "1.76.0"
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1829 ] Boost_VERSION_MACRO = "107600"
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1830 ] Boost_VERSION_MAJOR = "1"
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1831 ] Boost_VERSION_MINOR = "76"
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1832 ] Boost_VERSION_PATCH = "0"
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1833 ] Boost_VERSION_COUNT = "3"
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1857 ] Boost_LIB_PREFIX = ""
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1858 ] Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:953 ] _boost_COMPILER = "-vc142;-vc141;-vc140" (guessed)
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1894 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = "-mt"
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1972 ] _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "-x64" (detected)
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1976 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-"
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1977 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-gd"
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2037 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "C:/boost_1_76_0/stage/lib;C:/boost_1_76_0/lib;C:/boost_1_76_0/stage/lib;C:/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/boost_1_76_0/lib;C:/boost_1_76_0/../lib;C:/boost_1_76_0/stage/lib;C:/boost_1_76_0/../lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/boost_1_76_0/../lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/boost_1_76_0/../lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.0;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2038 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "C:/boost_1_76_0/stage/lib;C:/boost_1_76_0/lib;C:/boost_1_76_0/stage/lib;C:/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/boost_1_76_0/lib;C:/boost_1_76_0/../lib;C:/boost_1_76_0/stage/lib;C:/boost_1_76_0/../lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/boost_1_76_0/../lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/boost_1_76_0/../lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.0;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
CMake Warning at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1354 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1476 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2086 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package)
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2223 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_date_time-vc142-mt-x64-1_76;boost_date_time-vc142-mt-x64;boost_date_time-vc142-mt;boost_date_time-vc141-mt-x64-1_76;boost_date_time-vc141-mt-x64;boost_date_time-vc141-mt;boost_date_time-vc140-mt-x64-1_76;boost_date_time-vc140-mt-x64;boost_date_time-vc140-mt;boost_date_time-mt-x64-1_76;boost_date_time-mt-x64;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time
-- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2278 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_date_time-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_76;boost_date_time-vc142-mt-gd-x64;boost_date_time-vc142-mt-gd;boost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_76;boost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-x64;boost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd;boost_date_time-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_76;boost_date_time-vc140-mt-gd-x64;boost_date_time-vc140-mt-gd;boost_date_time-mt-gd-x64-1_76;boost_date_time-mt-gd-x64;boost_date_time-mt-gd;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time
-- Could NOT find Boost (missing: date_time) (found suitable version "1.76.0", minimum required is "1.76.0")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/jan.muhammad/source/repos/boost in cmake
```

Comment: Proper spelling for `BOOST_DEBUG` variable is `Boost_DEBUG` (see [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html), case matters!). With proper spelling, CMake will print the exact Boost library filename which is searched and exact directories where it is searched. Compare these filename and directories with your Boost installation.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have edited the spelling of Boost_DEBUG, however, there's still the same error. Any idea, how can I solve it?

Comment: The error message is the same, but configuration output should be changed: before the line `Could NOT find Boost` it should be debug information about searching for Boost. Use this information as I described in my previous comment.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have added the console output in my question at the last. I couldn't understand where the error lies. Can you please help me?

Comment: In the line `_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE` you could see the directories where Boost libraries are searched. Check that you have at least one of these directories. In the line `DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_RELEASE` you could see names of the library files which are searched. Check, that your directory has one of these files (with possible ``lib`` prefix and ``.lib`` extension). If you have no of these files, then find the **existed** file with the name contained ``date_time``. Then you need to determine, why your file is not searched.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
include_directories(${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR}) 
add_executable(progname file1.cxx file2.cxx) 
target_link_libraries(progname ${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR})
```

I always recommend using `Boost::boost` both for nice clean include of headers and linkage

```
add_executable(progname file1.cxx file2.cxx) 
target_link_libraries(progname Boost::boost Boost::date_time)
```

Also to have more meaning full cmake erros I guess you want to use
`find_package(Boost 1.76.0 COMPONENTS date_time REQUIRED)` and get rid of the `if(Boost_FOUND)` except if you have a meaning full alternative if you don't find boost.